# Why would having more matter than anti-matter neutrinos help make the rest of the universe be tipped towards matter?

Tags: particle-physics, big-bang, antimatter

My middle school daughter became fascinated after reading the article below about how the matter/anti-matter balance of neutrinos helped create the big bang, so decided to make it her term research paper topic for science.

https://www.nytimes.com/2020/04/15/science/physics-neutrino-antimatter-ichikawa-t2k.html

Excerpt from article below:

> Neutrinos are nature’s escape artists. Did they help us slip out of the Big Bang? Perhaps. Recent experiments in Japan have discovered a telltale anomaly in the behavior of neutrinos, and the results suggest that, amid the throes of creation and annihilation in the first moments of the universe, these particles could have tipped the balance between matter and its evil-twin opposite, antimatter.

> As a result, a universe that started out with a clean balance sheet — equal amounts of matter and antimatter — wound up with an excess of matter: stars, black holes, oceans, and us.

Abby (my daughter) did all research and found all the sources on what neutrinos were, how they worked, and what the experiments showed... Then she got completely stuck on the question of WHY would extra matter neutrinos make the rest of the universe, composed of other elementary particles, have more matter; given that each particle type matter/antimatter pair only seems to cancel each other out.

Both her science teacher and I have tried to find materials for her to understand this question, but unfortunately, we both ended up hitting a brick wall.

Any help would be appreciated, as I feel badly that I encouraged her to do such a tough research paper, and now it looks like she might have to start all over again...

Comment: It would be better to link an article that didn't require people to sign I to something to see, that or paraphrase certain segments from the article here (with appropriate credit to the source) so the question is self contained.

Comment: it makes you sign in? As I tried with a incognito browser and it didn't make me sign in,  I will copy (with credit) some of the relevant lines...

Comment: Hi! It's not said that there was an excess of matter neutrinos (why? would be the next question). If she is interested, the Rishon model states that in our Universe there were equal amounts of matter and antimatter from the start (so still today), without the T-rishons and V-rishons being annihilated. Each quark and lepton (and so neutrons, protons, etc.) is composed out of three of these rishons, families of quarks and leptons being excited states. In a parallel Universe, the same rishon particles can combine to form anti-quarks and anti-leptons. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishon_model

Comment: Huh, that’s a cool theory, thanks!